# Transit visa from Russia to Kyrgyzstan

Tags: air-travel

I am a Swedish citizen traveling to Kyrgyzstan via Russia. Do I need a transit visa while waiting for my flight iin 24 hours?

Answer (score 1):

If it is over 24 hours then you will need a transit visa

> A single transit visa is issued to Swedish and foreign nationals who pass the Russian Federation on travel to another destination country for a period of 10 days (road or rail) or up to 3 days (by air) upon presentation of tickets valid for departure from Russia, valid visa to border country or visa or passport issued by the country of destination.

But if it is no later than 24 hours and you are departing Russia on an international flight from the same airport you wont. I can't tell from your question if it is exactly 24 hours or not. But as long as it's **no later than 24 hours** and you are not transiting to another airport in Russia you are fine without a transit visa.

> Foreign nationals traveling with international airline and
>   international airport at the same airport in the Russian Federation
>   with delimited transitzon , which are provided with valid documents
>   for entry into the country of destination and airliner with stamped
>   departure date from the airport in Russia **no later than 24 hours after
>   arrival**, must not resolve transit visa .
>
> Transit visa is required, however, if the passenger leaves the transit
>   zone.

This information is from the [website](https://ifs-sweden.com/) you will need to use if you need to get a visa for Russia in Sweden.